# Why does using ROW_NUMBER() in an INSERT INTO command behave differently than expected?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This example is a bit convoluted, but basically I have a table with some existing data in it, and I want to re-sort (update a column value) based on the order of Ids I pass in.

If I run this set of SQL commands:

```
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D,E,B,A,C'

DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Id          VARCHAR(2),
    SortRank    INT,
    OptionValue INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, SortRank, OptionValue) VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1),
    ('B', 2, 1),
    ('C', 3, 3),
    ('D', 4, 2),
    ('E', 5, 3)

-- Storing existing values in table variable so we can re-insert records in new order without losing existing OptionValue values
DECLARE @Existing TABLE (
    Id          VARCHAR(2),
    OptionValue INT
)

INSERT INTO @Existing (Id, OptionValue)
    SELECT  Id, OptionValue
    FROM    @Table

DELETE
FROM    @Table

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, SortRank, OptionValue)
    SELECT      I.Id, I.SortRank, E.OptionValue
    FROM        (
                    SELECT  value AS Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SortRank
                    FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Ids, ',')
                ) AS I
                INNER JOIN @Existing AS E ON E.Id = I.Id
    ORDER BY    I.SortRank ASC

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

I get the following output (which is identical to what I first insert into @Table):

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| Id | SortRank | OptionValue |
+----+----------+-------------+
| A  |        1 |           1 |
| B  |        2 |           1 |
| C  |        3 |           3 |
| D  |        4 |           2 |
| E  |        5 |           3 |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

However, what I'm expecting to get back is this:

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| Id | SortRank | OptionValue |
+----+----------+-------------+
| D  |        1 |           2 |
| E  |        2 |           3 |
| B  |        3 |           1 |
| A  |        4 |           1 |
| C  |        5 |           3 |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

I can accomplish this by persisting data from the query with ROW_NUMBER() function into a temp table and then insert it into the main table in a separate operation like this:

```
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D,E,B,A,C'

DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Id          VARCHAR(2),
    SortRank    INT,
    OptionValue INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, SortRank, OptionValue) VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1),
    ('B', 2, 1),
    ('C', 3, 3),
    ('D', 4, 2),
    ('E', 5, 3)

-- Storing existing values in table variable so we can re-insert records in new order without losing existing OptionValue values
DECLARE @Existing TABLE (
    Id          VARCHAR(2),
    OptionValue INT
)

INSERT INTO @Existing (Id, OptionValue)
    SELECT  Id, OptionValue
    FROM    @Table

DELETE
FROM    @Table


SELECT      I.Id, I.SortRank, E.OptionValue
INTO        #Table
FROM        (
                SELECT  value AS Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS SortRank
                FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Ids, ',')
            ) AS I
            INNER JOIN @Existing AS E ON E.Id = I.Id
ORDER BY    I.SortRank ASC

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, SortRank, OptionValue)
    SELECT  Id, SortRank, OptionValue
    FROM    #Table

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

I can't figure out why the second approach works while the first fails, especially since the logic is basically the same, but I suspect it has to do with my understanding of how ROW_NUMBER() is calculated.

Any insight you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` ? the ordering is not deterministic

Comment: And string_split is also documented as returning rows in no specific order.

Comment: To qualify what SMor has said already: _The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string. You can override the final sort order by using an ORDER BY clause on the SELECT statement (ORDER BY value)._ REF: [STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems with your code.  You have:

- The `insert` into `@table` inserts no rows because `@existing` is empty.  So no modifications are made to the table.
- A `SELECT` query with no `ORDER BY`.  The results are in an indeterminate order.
- The `string_split()` function does *not* return values in a determined order.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

If you have no duplicates in the string, then you can fix the `select`:

```
    SELECT I.Id, I.SortRank, E.OptionValue
    FROM (SELECT value AS Id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + @ids + ',')) AS SortRank
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Ids, ',') s
         ) I JOIN
         @Existing E
         ON E.Id = I.Id
    ORDER BY I.SortRank ASC;
```

I think this is the full code you are trying to write:

```
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D,E,B,A,C';

DECLARE @Existing TABLE (
    the_id VARCHAR(2),
    SortRank    INT,
    OptionValue INT
);

INSERT INTO @Existing (the_Id, SortRank, OptionValue) VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1),
    ('B', 2, 1),
    ('C', 3, 3),
    ('D', 4, 2),
    ('E', 5, 3)

-- Storing existing values in table variable so we can re-insert records in new order without losing existing OptionValue values
DECLARE @New TABLE (
    id int identity primary key,
    the_id VARCHAR(2),
    SortRank    INT,
    OptionValue INT
);

INSERT INTO @New (the_Id, SortRank, OptionValue)
    SELECT I.the_Id, I.SortRank, E.OptionValue
    FROM (SELECT value AS the_Id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + @ids + ',')) AS SortRank
          FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Ids, ',') s
         ) I JOIN
         @Existing E
         ON E.the_Id = I.the_id
    ORDER BY I.SortRank ASC;

SELECT *
FROM @New
ORDER BY id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7da6db3e4c6e0ca4d8aab8558926e35) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution can be simplified to use `CHARINDEX()` to detemine the relative position of the `Id` in `@Ids`. And that use that as the `ORDER BY` in `ROW_NUMBER()`

You don't need additional temp table or `STRING_SPLIT()`

```
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(MAX) = 'D,E,B,A,C'

DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Id          VARCHAR(2),
    SortRank    INT,
    OptionValue INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Id, SortRank, OptionValue) VALUES
    ('A', 1, 1),
    ('B', 2, 1),
    ('C', 3, 3),
    ('D', 4, 2),
    ('E', 5, 3)

SELECT  t.Id,
        SortRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + t.Id + ',', ',' + @Ids + ',')),
        t.OptionValue
FROM    @Table t
ORDER BY SortRank
```